# Ensure In Process Records are Unique ActiveMQ

Tags: asynchronous, activemq-classic

I'm working on a system where clients enter data into a program and the save action posts a message to activemq for more time intensive processing.

We are running into rare occasions where a record will be updated by a client twice in a row and a consumer on that activemq queue will process the two records at the same time. I'm looking for a way to ensure that messages containing records with the same identity are processed in-order and only one at a time. To be clear if a record with ID 1, 1, and 2 (in that order) are sent to activemq, 1 would process, then 2 (if 1 was still in process) and finally 1.

Another requirement, (due to volume) requires that the consumer be multi-threaded, so there may be 16 threads accessing that queue. This would have to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Have you looked into http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-preserve-order-of-messages.html? I haven't used this in production though, so I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have multiple threads reading that queue and you want the solution to be close to ActiveMQ you have to think about how you scale related to order concerns.

If you have multiple consumers, they may operate at different speed and you can never be sure which consumer goes before the other. The only way is to have a single consumer (you can still achieve High Availability by using [exclusive-consumers](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html)).

You can, however, segment the load in other ways. How depends a lot on your application. If you can create, say 16 "worker" queues (or whatever your max consumer count would be) and distribute load to these queues while guarantee that requests from a single user always come to the same "worker queue", message order will remain per user.

If you have no good way to divide users into groups, simply take the `userID mod MAX_CONSUMER_THREADS` as a simple solution.

There may be better ways to deal with this problem in the consumer logic itself. Like keeping track of the sequence number and postpone updates that are out of order ([scheduled delay](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html) can be used for that).